# Unable to open tdb '/var/lib/sss/db/config.ldb'

Tags: linux, ssh, ldap, sssd

I have an Oracle Linux Server release 8.2 system that I recently updated via yum. Before the update ssh could authenticate against a LDAP server, sles linux. In the logs I now see (details below):

[sssd[pam]] [ldb] (0x0020): Unable to open tdb '/var/lib/sss/db/config.ldb': Permission denied
[sssd[pam]] [ldb] (0x0020): Failed to connect to '/var/lib/sss/db/config.ldb' with backend 'tdb': Unable to open tdb '/var/lib/sss/db/config.ldb': Permission denied
[sssd[pam]] [confdb_init] (0x0010): Unable to open config database [/var/lib/sss/db/config.ldb]
[sssd[pam]] [server_setup] (0x0010): The confdb initialization failed
sssd-pam.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
sssd-pam.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

After the update and susequent reboot I noticed the problem. I immediately check the sshd, sssd, selinux, etc. configuration files but they have not been modified in months. This server is rebooted once a week, so I don't think it is a configuration change that snuck in over the last months or a preexisting problem.

I have tried setting selinux into permissive mode without improvement. In addition, the auth.log does not mention sssd.

I have removed the files under /var/lib/sss/db/* after a restart of sssd the files are recreated, including config.ldb. But the above problem still exists.

A getent passwd foo returns the correct information, so basic communication with the ldap server does work.

If anyone has an idea or hints, I would greatly appreciate them.

Comment: Are there any SELinux audit entries for when you restart the sssd service?  Check the output of `ausearch -m avc -ts recent` within 5 minutes of restarting sssd to check.

Comment: The command you suggested gave the response <no matches> before an ssh attempt and also after.

Comment: It did you check when restarting sssd?  That’s what I’m asking.

Comment: Yes. I stopped sssd, started it again and waited about a minute. Then ran the command. Then attempted an ssh as a ldap user (so not local) and ran the command again. I hope that clarifies the situation.